# Is closing (or flagging) this question valid?

Tags: discussion

Reference https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2899/no-time-limit-holdem

> Are there any poker sites which allow for days or hours to think for on each street instead of the usual seconds? This sounds like an awesome idea.

This question feels to me like it simply doesn't belong on poker.stackexchange.com (or probably any other site in the SE network). The flag options don't seem to have anything reasonable, and as I don't have enough rep to vote to close questions I don't know the status there.

Is this question appropriate for closing / removal, or am I off base?

Update: Since my posting this, the question has been closed, so I suppose I've got that as my answer. Leaving this question here though in case it spurs further discussion.

Comment: ah like 'correspondence poker' instead of correspondence chess?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly feel this question should not have been closed. In fact, I just came here (to meta) to ask why this was closed. The reason given is that the "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts..."

How? The OP is just asking for websites. This is FACTUAL information. NOT opinion based whatsoever! Closing this question is absurd and an abuse of admin power in my opinion.

Actually, I also was curious to find a site like the one OP is seeking. And I've been playing LHE for 10 years. I also disagree with mah's comments on this question. How could this be useful? Think about playing live poker. You actually do have infinite time to make decisions. Think about websites where you post hands and ask questions. Actually you are freezing a hand on some particular street and analyzing it for a long time.

In my particular case, I want to play HUHU with a friend that's new to poker, using play money, and give her infinite time to think about decisions. Can we go on PokerStars and play HUHU for play money? Yes, but the table are super fast for her. I'll crush her. She has no time to even think about the right decisions.

I very strongly feel there are legitimate reasons for a site like the one OP is seeking and also closing for the reasons given is ridiculous. It's not an opinion based question at all.

Comment: _Think about playing live poker. You actually do have infinite time to make decisions._ No, you don't. You have until one person protests and the floor manager agrees it's been too long; the floor manager starts a clock establishing a limit. Whether online or live, the house has two very compelling reasons to enforce a time limit. First: they make money by taking their rake and if they allow too much time without any action to pass, they lose money, without which they cannot stay in business. Second: the other 99.99% of players will not tolerate it and will not play at that establishment.

Comment: I've never seen it happen, and I have thousands of hours of live experience. You're missing the point anyway.

Comment: I agree, stating websites that may offer this is factual. Bias towards whether one is better than another is not. That's the focus of the reasoning given in this case. That's my understanding of this case. That said, no commercial business will *ever* cater to this; they're here to make money. Best just to play live at home I reckon.

Comment: @TobyBooth This question should have never been closed. It is on topic, it is relevant. Indeed there has been a site that played poker just like this, that was interesting to many poker players. It is an excellent question, and you closed it because you did not understand it, not because it was bad. Let the community up vote or down vote these kinds of questions. This closure is an example of unhealthy elitism here. (As you asked)

Answer (score 0):

Questions like this probably are too open to debate, where all answers are valid. It seems like the right choice to close it, and if it had been me, this would've been prominent in my reasoning for doing so.

Comment: This is a valid question. Should of been left. A very early site at poker.com (the domain long ago sold) did indeed host a poker game for fun, where a hand took days due to technology.

Comment: Respectfully, it may be about poker, but not in the sense of learning how to play. Time spent to take a move is not a skill anyone needs to or is required to, or would find any difficulty in understanding or learning.

Comment: Respectfully, its not your call to close it. Let these questions be. Let them be up or down voted and let the community have the say. Arguing about rather or not it has value, is academic. Toby please sit back and see what value these things have. When I say elitist and manipulative, this is what I mean, you are not letting things go the way a community should go when you decide to kill a question simply because you cannot find value. You should always consider that you just might be missing the value. Think in terms of why it should stay open, not why you should close it.